# How do I reference a piece of data's name with a '-' in it, using react/JS?

Tags: javascript

I am looking to reference the total-fees property of an object:

[The object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqbdt.png)

In react, the '-' causes problems in referencing this property. I have tried using camelCase, and quotations marks, but no luck.

[The code attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwzrR.png)

Comment: replace .total-fees with ['total-fees'],
what you write is property 'total' from original minus fees variable

Answer (score 0):

Got it :D

data.row.original['total-fees']

Answer (score -1):

You are using negate symbol(!) with the key, `data.row.original.total-fees`. What this means is that your return statement will run only when `data.row.original.total-fees` is false or 0, but it is actually null.

So, what you can try is:

1). `console.log(data.row.original.total-fees);  //output: null`

2). `if(data.row.original.total-fees===null) return "Response";`